# To Prove NP-Completeness

Tags: np-complete, reductions, hamiltonian-path

Given a Directed Graph G, and some subsets of vertices T1,T2,..Tn(These subset can intersect) , is there a path in this graph such that it is acyclic and contains exactly 3 vertices from each Ti. I'm not sure , but I have an intuition that this is a problem that can be reduced from hamiltonian path problem , just can't figure out how to reduce it . Because in HAM-Path all vertices have to be visited , in this question though all vertices need not be visited in the path.

Comment: What's the context where you encountered this problem?  Can you credit the original source where you saw it?  What's the motivation?

Comment: This question appears to be identical to https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/155750/755.  If it is not, please [edit] the question to make clear how this question is different.